# Prolog print out 2 dimension table

Tags: arrays, printing, prolog

i have  a square with start and finish points, also places where i can't go. And my program must find a way to reach finish:

```
ar_galima([], _, _):-!.
ar_galima([Prad|Galas],Kelias, X) :- not(Prad == X), not(member(X, Kelias)), ar_galima(Galas, Kelias, X). 

gener(Stac_M, Stac_K, k(A,B), k(Y,B)) :-  Y is A + 1, Y > 0, Y =< Stac_M, B =< Stac_K.
gener(Stac_M, Stac_K, k(A,B), k(Y,B)) :-  Y is A - 1, Y > 0, Y =< Stac_M, B =< Stac_K.
gener(Stac_M, Stac_K, k(A,B), k(A,Y)) :-  Y is B + 1, Y > 0, Y =< Stac_K, A =< Stac_M.
gener(Stac_M, Stac_K, k(A,B), k(A,Y)) :-  Y is B - 1, Y > 0, Y =< Stac_K, A =< Stac_M.

paieska(_, _,_,Tikslas,Tikslas,[], _):-!.
paieska(Stac_M, Stac_K, Draudziama, Prad, Tikslas, [K|Kelias], Kelias2) :- 
      gener(Stac_M, Stac_K, Prad, K), ar_galima(Draudziama, Kelias2, K), 
      paieska(Stac_M, Stac_K, Draudziama, K, Tikslas, Kelias, [K|Kelias2]).

trasa(Ilgis, Aukstis, Draudziama, k(X,Y), Tikslas, Kelias) :-
      paieska(Ilgis,Aukstis, Draudziama, k(X,Y), Tikslas,Kelias, []).
```

i find routes to finish and now i'm stuck outputing the route (a list) into 2 dimension table in terminal (well, a simple graphic show of the route).

example of list to output:`X = [k(2, 1), k(3, 1), k(4, 1), k(4, 2), k(4, 3), k(4, 4)] ;`

Could someone suggesst me how should i output a 2 dimension table into terminal?

**EDIT:**

`X` should be printed:

```
 + + + *
 + + + *
 + + + *
 + * * *
```

print perdicate could look like this:

> printTable(N, M, X) :- ...

where N is number of rows, M is number of columns and X is list of coordinates.

Comment: Please translate predicate and variables names to (quasi-)English. It's not even clear which predicate you are calling at top level.

Comment: it doesn't matter. i have result X, which is list with coordinates X and Y. i would like to draw table where boxes with these coordinates should look different . see EDIT above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with something like this:

```
print_table(H, W, L):-
  succ(W, W1),
  print_table(4, 1, H, W1, L).

print_table(1, W, _, W, _):- !.
print_table(Y, W, H, W, L):-
  succ(NY, Y),
  nl,
  !,
  print_table(NY, 1, H, W, L).
print_table(Y, X, H, W, L):-
  (member(k(X, Y), L)->C='* ';C='+ '),
  write(C),
  succ(X, NX),
  !,
  print_table(Y, NX, H, W, L).
```